# How to use fail2ban for Nginx error "Primary script unknown"

Tags: nginx, fail2ban, ufw

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Fail2ban, but errors like this are not filtered.
This error appears in /var/log/nginx/error.log. How do I make settings in Fail2ban to block bots like this?

2020/12/31 18:02:34 [error] 674#674: *1003 FastCGI sent in stderr: "**Primary script unknown**" while reading response header from upstream, client: *xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx*, server: *mydomain.com*, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/eshop-magic/download.php?file=../../../../wp-config.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "*www.mydomain.com*"

Note: I want to block all IP addressed trying to access non-existent web pages, using fail2ban. I'm having trouble building a proper regex on filter.d

Comment: Are you sure you want to block this? See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/517190/nginx-1-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unknown)

Comment: Yes. But block them using fail2ban, not nginx.

Answer (score 4):

Add the section `[nginx-badbots]` in your `jail.local`

```
[nginx-badbots]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = nginx-badbots
logpath  = /var/log/nginx/error.log
maxretry = 2
```

Create a filter file called `nginx-badbots.conf` inside `filter.d`

```
[Definition]

failregex = FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" .*, client: <HOST>

ignoreregex =
```

Restart fail2ban

```
service fail2ban restart
```

Check your `nginx-badbots` jail

```
fail2ban-client status nginx-badbots
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention blocking access of scripts to `wp-content`'s PHP scripts...

It would be quite a valid statement that the majority of *good* plugins will execute only through WordPress's front controller (`/index.php`) and have nice SEO URLs.

A good plugin would not allow its execution from links of sort `/wp-content/plugins/<foo>/<foo|bar|blah>.php`. The ones that do, are "bad", or badly coded :-).

So if you keep your plugin base clean, you don't have such plugins and can deem any requests to `/wp-content/*.php` malicious.

Blocking those can be done automatically, but Fail2Ban won't be quite a good choice there because it needs to scan through the logs first. Instead, why not route such malicious requests directly to a script which automatically bans such IPs in the firewall. No log scanning, immediate blocking.

I have covered this approach in [honeypot blocking](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/nginx-honeypot-the-easiest-and-fastest-way-to-block-bots) and last paragraphs of [secure NGINX configuration for WordPress](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/best-practice-secure-nginx-configuration-for-wordpress):

```
    location /wp-content/ { 
        # other PHP files cause automatic ban:
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include includes/honeypot.conf;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the honeypot article is for FirewallD but you can easily adopt it to whatever other firewalls there in other distros.